# how to keep a struct pointer outside a function in C

Tags: c, struct

I make a struct array in C and i want to initialize it in a void function. If i use return function it's well but if i use void function i have some problems.
Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Essai{
    char *nom;
    struct Essai* next;
} Essai;

void initialise(Essai* essai){
    struct Essai *newE = malloc(sizeof(Essai));
    newE->next = NULL;
    printf("What's your name ? ");
    scanf("%s", newE->nom);
    if(essai  != NULL){
        essai = newE;
    }else{
        struct Essai* temp = essai;
        while(temp->next != NULL) temp = temp->next;
        temp->next = newE;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Essai *var = NULL;
    initialise(var);
    printf("nom : %s", var->nom);
    return 0;
}
```

In the function essai is well created but outside the function it become NULL.

Comment: `initialize(Essai **essai);`

Comment: thank @Kira. can  you give me a little example of that?

Comment: Also, your scanf()  is rigged to blow up, since you're passing it an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that arguments to functions are passed *by value*, meaning that they are copied and the function only modifies the copy.

To make changes inside the function which is visible when the function returns, you need to emulate "call by reference", by passing a pointer. This includes passing pointers as pointer-to-pointer:

```
void initialise(Essai** essai){
    ...
    *essai = newE;
    ...
}

int main(void)
{
    Essai *var = NULL;
    initialise(&var);
    ...
}
```

---

Another solution is to return the pointer from the function:

```
Essai *initialise(Essai* essai){
    ...
    return essai;
}

int main(void)
{
    Essai *var = NULL;
    var = initialise(var);
    ...
}
```

Comment: thank you @Joachim Pileborg but i don't understand. I think that an example can help me very well

Comment: Ok thank you mery much @Joachim Pileborg. I am going to try it this night. Good weekend

Comment: How i just come to try it and it is well. Big thank to @Joachim Pileborg.